# Google Vault API HttpError 500 "Internal error encountered."

Tags: google-api, google-api-client

I'm getting the following error when trying to create a hold using the Google Vault API:

> HttpError 500 when requesting
>   https://vault.googleapis.com/v1/matters/{matterId}/holds?alt=json
>   returned "Internal error encountered."

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account
import googleapiclient.discovery

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/ediscovery']
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = './serviceaccount.json'
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)
delegated_credentials = credentials.with_subject('delegateuser@example.com')
client = googleapiclient.discovery.build('vault', 'v1', credentials=delegated_credentials)

data = { 'name': 'test', 'accounts': [{'email': 'testuser@example.com' }], 'corpus': 'MAIL', 'query': { 'mailQuery': {'terms': 'to:ceo@company.com'} }}

results = client.matters().holds().create(matterId='{matterId}', body=data).execute()
```

I've replaced the actual matterId string with {matterId}.
Creating matters, listing matters and listing holds work just fine.
I've tried different combinations of fields to include in the request body but the docs are not clear as to which are required...

Answer (score 1):

It turns out you can't use 'email' in holds().create() - you must use accountId, or the 'id' number for the gmail user.

Answer (score 0):

You can use emails to create holds
https://developers.google.com/vault/guides/holds#create_a_hold_for_mail_on_specific_user_accounts_with_a_search_query